# How to keep session details alive for long time in PHP and when internet is gone

Tags: php, mysql

For an Online exam application using PHP,JS,MySql, I have an exam that has 3 Hours. 
All the questions are loaded in client side and after the time-out/submit only-we communicate with server for valuation of exam and results.
When internet is gone for Some Hours/Time i cant calculate the exam results and i am losting my attended exam details for valuation.

Comment: Neither PHP nor Mysql can fix your internet connection... It's called an 'Online exam' for a reason - it may not be designed for (temporary) offline usage.

Comment: Simple, use cookies.

Comment: i think session_set_cookie_params() will help, ...

Comment: I used the coockies...but... after 2 HRs when submitting the exam automatically logout..i used setcookie("PHPSESSID", session_id(), time() + 3600 * 6);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I understand, your problem is PHPSESSION expiration (because PHP drop session after 30 minutes). So I recommend store your session data into database and make session cookie expiration time ~3 hours (exam time).

Also you can make PHP SESSION live time more long ([How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)). But i think more right way - store all data in database

Answer (score 0):

When the [internet is gone](http://static.fjcdn.com/pictures/What_0b9a7e_809814.jpg), we might all be screwed up anyway...